# Is there a resource for generating appropriate goods for a post-apocalyptic looting?

Tags: equipment, tool-recommendation, generator

One of the problems I have running post-apocalyptic survival games is that the genera expects a very detailed and strict tracking of equipment.  This usually goes fine until the party tracks down a supermarket, clothing store, gas station snack shack, random house, et cetera, at which point it would be really useful to have some kind of (preferably digitalized) tool which I can have automatically generate shop inventories and things.  Does such a tool exist?  Whence may I acquire it?  I am certainly capable of making tables or using, for example, the [UPC database](http://www.upcdatabase.com) to generate random items; I am looking for a full-fledged generation tool, with the following desired features (though it's ok if a suggestion lacks some or even all of these, the more of these a suggestion meets the better it is as an answer):

- large item database
- editable database
- multiple generators with different items/item frequencies (based off of the kind of building)
- able to create new generators
- digitally stored
- cheap/free
- lists editable after generation
- lists can be saved

  - as .txt files
  - and easily printed
- Provides for: Apartment, hospital, library, plant nursery, church, police station
- Generates full item lists rapidly-- at least 3-4 retail stores' worth of goods per minute

and with the following required features (if it doesn't do these, it's not an answer):

- modern day setting possible
- generates realistic building inventories (in terms of scale.  Appropriate content is less important)
- content is based off of the type of source.
- Provides for: Supermarket, convenience store, retail store, electronics store, sporting goods store

  - or is capable of doing so without requiring more work than it would take me to make a table for each by hand
- Generates content at a usable speed-- it should take no longer than 1 hour to generate a large building.

Please note that while the content needs to be generatable at a reasonable speed, it does not need to be comprehensible within the same time frame.  Particularly detailed generators yielding mock-inventories for retail stores might produce many pages of material per store, and this is fine, provided it can do so for a single store in less than one hour or so.

Comment: Not an answer, but since you mentioned the ability to create new generators: [Random Generator Wiki - Treasures](http://www.random-generator.com/index.php?title=Treasure) is something every GM should know about.

Comment: What do you mean by *realistic invertory in terms of scale*? The shop inventory of a supermarket is likely dozens if not hundreds of pages of items - is this what you want?

Comment: @fgysin Yes.  I have no issue with having to go through (or making my players go through) 100+ pages of inventory text, if a generator managed to provide the kinds of intense detail that an actual store inventory manifest contains.  I am, however, also okay with not being able to deal with the even larger scale of warehouses and ocean freighters, which probably have thousand page inventories.  You should note, though, that most of the items in a supermarket list are fairly similar and a less detailed generator might only yield 30-40 items while maintaining the same total volume.

Comment: I don't even know where to get the raw data on this... Apart from actually asking supermarkets/fire stations/hospitals for their inventory.

Answer (score 3):

You could construct a table for yourself that had some basic categories of the types of things poeple might find, like:

- food
- clothing
- weapons
- tools
- transporation
- found nothing

Weight the values to the relative scarcities you want, and roll on the table when they scrounge.  A second roll could be used to see how or how good their find is.

---

Or, you could try here: 
http://warehousebasement.com/
It is website where each page load "opens a random box".  The "items" described are often somewhat odd, but you edit on-the-fly to a simple and setting-appropriate item.  The site would be a jumping off point.